# best way to replicate the threaded conversation UI in twitter

Tags: user-interface, threaded-comments

I will have a series of threaded conversations, and want to be able to display these threads in the most simple and intuitive way on the site.  The twitter.com way of sliding into a reply makes a lot of sense.

What would be the simplest way to do this?  Or are there any other interesting ways of displaying this kind of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Github's tree slider:

https://github.com/blog/760-the-tree-slider